# SmartGWT TabSet remove or hide Tab

Tags: tabs, smartgwt

I have a TabSet with 5 tabs. Tab A is the 1st one and is selected by default. onClick in it, I open a 6th Tab, which uses the same viewComponent as Tab A, with some small modifications. On execution of some functions in this 6th Tab, I need to close it and return to Tab A. removeTab destroys the viewComponent that I need, and using updateTab(currentTab, null), then selectTab(Tab A) doesn't destroy the 6th Tab. I need to either hide it, or even better - destroy it, but avoid destroying the viewComponent. How can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to do...  Why open a "6th tab" instead of modifying the "1st tab" after a click on some component? You could simply update the viewComponent in "1st tab", execute your functions and re-update the component.

Comment: It's the client who wants to add a new Tab, the same as Tab A, with only a slight difference. This behaviour was accepted by my project manager, so I need to execute it like that. I currently have 2 mediators with 99% equal code, and I'm trying to optimize this mess.

Comment: I would recommend refactoring the code, have two instances of the view component, and destroy the "6th tab" as in your other question I answered.  This way it won't impact the view component on 1st tab !

Comment: Another option is not to add/remove 6th tab, but keep it in the tab set all the time. It should be disabled by default and enabled when clicked on Tab A. And disable and select Tab A after operation on Tab 6.

Comment: disable/enable will still make it visible, and the client doesn't want to see it at all. Besides, there are other Tabs that need to show/hide, so it'll be too compicated to have all 10 of them available all the time. Thanks for the idea, however :)